# Using intents for passing data

Tags: android, forms, sqlite, android-intent

How do you send data from one activity to another using intents.

(Note this is a two-part question, the sending and the receiving).

I'm creating a form, and I want to save the answers to every question in an sqlite database.

Answer (score 1):

**Sending** (Activity 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyCurentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", "enter value here");
startActivity(intent);
```

**Receiving** (Activity 2):

```
String text = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data easily using Bundle.

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putString("key", value);

Intent intent=new Intent(TopicListController.this,UnitConverter.class);
intent.putExtras(b);

startActivity(intent);
```

You can recieve data in your other activity like this as follow:

```
Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
String s=b.getString("select");
```

Answer (score 0):

To send from the Activity

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("name","My name is");
    startActivity(myIntent);
```

To retrieve in the secod

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
           String name=bundle.getString("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(yourActivity.this, nextActvity.class);

i.putExtra("dataName", data);

//recieving

Intent i = nextActivity.this.getIntent();


 string s =  i.getStringExtra("dataName", defaultValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

**To pass the data using intent from the current activity use the following code**

```
             Intent in = new Intent(YourClassContext, nextActivity.class);
             in.putExtra("name","value");
             startActivity(in);
```

**To get the intent data passed in the next activity use the following code**

```
     Intent i = nextActivity.this.getIntent();
     String intentDatapassed = i.getStringExtra("name", defaultValue);
```