# intent datapassing in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass object from one activity to another in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)
>   [Using intents for passing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006957/using-intents-for-passing-data)

Is it possible to pass a value from one activity to other activity. That is there are 3 activities, I have 1 string in 1st activity, I want this string in 3rd activity.

One more I am not going straightly to 3rd activity. I am going form 1 to 2 and 3. In that how can I have a string in activity 1 in activity ..

Comment: Dublicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006957/using-intents-for-passing-data

Comment: Hi..thanks for downvoting...By just starting an activity i can pass the value from 1 screen to other..But what i want is,when i press one button it will do calcultion,and have it on an float variable.And it will start 1 activity,but i don't want that float in that activity,i want that in another activity..How its possible??thats i posted here..

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Application life cycle.

Create Application class, save/update values and access it in the activity where ever you want.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
public static String value;


}
```

In activity, to save any value, use

```
MyApplication.value = "some value";
```

In other activity, if you want this value,

```
String myValue = MyApplication.value;
```

Another way is, you can pass intent extras in each activity.